# Error al cargar DLL en Java 8, pero funciona en java 6

Tags: java, smartcard

mi intención es usar smartcards en un proyecto de java, estoy usando el código de prueba que viene con el lector, el cual funciona al compilar en java 6, pero necesito hacerlo en la versión 8 ya que uso JavaFX. Parece que el problema surge al tratar de utilizar un método del archivo Jacspcsc.dll, aclaro que no sale un mensaje, el programa sólo se detiene y no muestra ningún mensaje. También aclaro que al cambiar el jre a 6 en eclipse o netbeans, la parte de la smartcard corre sin problema. Aqúi la parte de código que creo que tiene el inconveniente:

```
ret = SCardEstablishContext(dwscope, pvReserved1, pvReserved2, hContext);
```

Este es un método nativo:

```
private native int SCardEstablishContext(int dwscope,
                                        int pvReserved1,
                                        int pvReserved2,
                                        int phContext);
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Que tipo de lector y de tarjetas usas?

Comment: Estoy utilizando el ACR1281U de ACS. La tarjeta que uso es la que venía con el producto, una ACOS3.

Comment: Te recomiendo que utilices el API Java SmartCardIO, perteneciente al API estandar de Java. [Este puede ser un buen punto de inicio](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=javax.smartcardio.CardTerminal).

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias, me pondré en ello.